# Using Javascript in mdx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

Hello everyone I'm building a storybook of a design system and I want to use the Docs and Knobs addons. I'm creating the stories in mdx files and I'm making the first story as a preview of the component which the user can try changing the different props possible in knobs.

```
        import { select } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';

const label = 'Colors';
const options = {
  Red: 'red',
  Blue: 'blue',
  Yellow: 'yellow',
  Rainbow: ['red', 'orange', 'etc'],
  None: null,
};
const defaultValue = 'red';
const groupId = 'GROUP-ID1';

const value = select(label, options, defaultValue, groupId);
```

I'm trying to use the implementation from the addon's documentation but It's not working in the mdx file. Does any one has a solution for this or another approach. I want to have the documentation with Docs addon and knobs to try different props of the component.

Comment: Have you seen [this issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/8342)? They mention to include withKnobs in the Meta decorators. `<Meta title="Desktop|Image Gallery" component={ImageGallery} decorators={[withKnobs]} />`

Comment: Perfect! thank you for your help :)